# What happens to dryads when their tree is destroyed?

Tags: greek, nymphs

What happens to [dryads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dryad), the tree nymphs of Greek mythology,  when their tree is cut down, burned or otherwise destroyed? Do they die or do they move on to a new tree?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the tale of [Erysichthon of Thessaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erysichthon_of_Thessaly) and his daughter Mestra - as relayed by Ovid - dryads do not survive the destruction of their tree:

> But Erysichthon, heedless of all things,
>   ordered his slaves to fell the sacred oak,
>   and as they hesitated, in a rage
>   the wretch snatched from the hand of one an axe,
>   and said, “If this should be the only oak
>   loved by the goddess of this very grove,
>   or even were the goddess in this tree,
>   I'll level to the ground its leafy head.”
>   So boasted he, and while he swung on high
>   his axe to strike a slanting blow, the oak
>   beloved of Ceres, uttered a deep groan
>   and shuddered. Instantly its dark green leaves
>   turned pale, and all its acorns lost their green,
>   and even its long branches drooped their arms.
>   But when his impious hand had struck the trunk,
>   and cut its bark, red blood poured from the wound,—
>   as when a weighty sacrificial bull
>   has fallen at the altar, streaming blood
>   spouts from his stricken neck. All were amazed.
>   And one of his attendants boldly tried
>   to stay his cruel axe, and hindered him;
>   but Erysichthon, fixing his stern eyes
>   upon him, said, “Let this, then, be the price
>   of all your pious worship!” So he turned
>   the poised axe from the tree, and clove his head
>   sheer from his body, and again began
>   to chop the hard oak. From the heart of it
>   these words were uttered; “Covered by the bark
>   of this oak tree I long have dwelt a Nymph,
>   beloved of Ceres, and before my death
>   it has been granted me to prophesy,
>   that I may die contented. Punishment
>   for this vile deed stands waiting at your side.”
>
> <sub>Source: Ovid. Metamorphoses. Brookes More. Boston. Cornhill Publishing Co. 1922.</sub>

Comment: awww, sadface...

Answer (score 0):

Spirit, soul, cannot be destroyed.  Therefore a tree spirit will not die but merely transmute when a tree is felled, in the same way that the human soul does not die when the body dies.

Comment: Do you have any references that back up the idea that the Greeks believed that the soul could not be destroyed?  It is not a universal belief.

Comment: @Chenmunka It's often implied. The dead all end up in Hades, and there's no evidence that comes to mind about someone being zapped from existence. They can always come back from Hades.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure there's evidence of ancient Greeks believing tree souls transmuted.